# vlookup to join table from two different files and get the data

Tags: sql, excel

I post the question again as my previous post content is incorrect.

I have two excel files , they have the common filed ( student ID ) , I would like to join the tables so that the output as below table ( after vlookup ) , would advise what can I do ? thanks

I use office 2019

## Table 1 ( from file A )

[image]

## Table 2 ( from file B , not the same file as file A)

[image]

## After vlookup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply in column C of Table2 in 'file B' the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;[fileA.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$B$4;2;FALSE)
```

where column A of 'file B' is column 'student ID' and 'Sheet1' within 'file A' contains Table1 in range A1:B4 headers included

Please accept my answer if it covered your question.